# Endless loop at the touch of a button

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I need to start endless loop by pressing Space (for example) and end it pressing Space again

```
@win.event
def on_draw():
    (some code of drawing)


@win.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global x,y,z,t
    elif symbol == key.SPACE:
        t += 0.05
        x = ((1 - t) ** 3) * (-180) + 3 * t * ((1 - t) ** 2) * (100) + 3 * (t ** 2) * (1 - t) * (0) + (t ** 3) * (200)
        y = ((1 - t) ** 3) * 70 + 3 * t * ((1 - t) ** 2) * (140) + 3 * (t ** 2) * (1 - t) * (140) + (t ** 3) * (
        70)
        z = ((1 - t) ** 3) * 0 + 3 * t * ((1 - t) ** 2) * (100) + 3 * (t ** 2) * (1 - t) * (100) + (t ** 3) * (
        0)
        (here should be a function of endless moving (drawing) while Space haven't pressed again)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right choice to do it. You already have a loop, the game loop. Use it!

Create 2 state variables `start_loop` and `run_loop`:

```py
start_loop = False
run_loop = False
```

If <kbd>space</kbd> is pressed then you've to decide what to do.
If the loop is not running (`not run_loop`), then start the loop by setting `start_loop = True.`
If the loop is running, then stop the loop by `run_loop = False`.

```py
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):

    if symbol == key.SPACE:
        if not run_loop:
            start_loop = True
        else:
            run_loop = False
```

In the main loop you can have to distinguish 3 cased.

1. `start_loop` is `True`. Do the initializations and set the states to run the loop in the next frame (`start_loop = False`, `run_loop = True`)
2. `run_loop` is `True`. Do the code in the loop
3. default case, which does some drawing

```py
def on_draw():

    global x,y,z,t

    if start_loop:
        start_loop = False
        run_loop = True

        t += 0.05
        x = ((1 - t) ** 3) * (-180) + 3 * t * ((1 - t) ** 2) * (100) + 3 * (t ** 2) * (1 - t) * (0) + (t ** 3) * (200)
        y = ((1 - t) ** 3) * 70 + 3 * t * ((1 - t) ** 2) * (140) + 3 * (t ** 2) * (1 - t) * (140) + (t ** 3) * (70)
        z = ((1 - t) ** 3) * 0 + 3 * t * ((1 - t) ** 2) * (100) + 3 * (t ** 2) * (1 - t) * (100) + (t ** 3) * (0)

    elif run_loop:

        # this is the loop
        # [...] (here should be a function of endless moving (drawing) while Space haven't pressed again)
        pass

    else:

        # this is default
        # [...] (some code of drawing)
```

---

Of course you've to add a schedule function by [`schedule_interval`], which runs the loop in an specified interval.

```py
def run_loop(dt):
    on_draw()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(run_loop, 0.1) # run every tenth of a second
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: the loop works, but it activates when Space pressed and begin working when any other key pressed and work just for one cycle. And it draws just the begining and the end of cycle, but i need animation, so i can see all steps between start and end

Comment: @PopeyeTheSailor Of course you need a schedule function. Sorry, I didn't know that you don't have one. See the last part of the answer, which Iv'e added right now.